# How does water deionization process work?

Tags: water, ions, water-treatment

What are the technical/scientific details behind the process of water deionization? How does deionization machines like those manufactured by [Millipore](http://www.millipore.com/) work?

Comment: Check out this page: http://www.millipore.com/lab_water/clw4/type1&tabno=2

Comment: @Michiel - If you could summarize/explain the process, that would be a good answer.

Comment: As pointed out by Michiel, there is a lot of info on Merck's Millipore website. You can get a [pdf with some technical specifications for each equipment](http://www.millipore.com/publications.nsf/a73664f9f981af8c852569b9005b4eee/61580c0c14aa9d56852579bf0065f20b/$FILE/PB1032EN00_MM.pdf).

Comment: @BenNorris - I don't have that much knowledge on the topic to expand on the information already given on that website and I don't think summarizing a different webpage is going to do any good in helping the OP. Typically a bit more extensive explanation is easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Most cost/energy efficient method to make deionized water is reverse osmosis. The mechanism is to apply external pressure to water and force it to go through a layer or layers of semipermeable membrane.